# Serialize an IEnumerable<DayOfWeek> to a javascript client in which format

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, momentjs

I send an IEnumerable to a javascript client. I would like to know what is the best format to send those values to the client that the consumption and computation with those values works best with angularJS itself or the angularjs/moment.js library?

Send the values as integers 0,1,2,3,4,5,6 or Sunday/Monday/Tuesday etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think *dayOfTheWeek* value can be sent as an integer. As, it is treated the same way in JS only i.e as integer..

**JS**

```
var d = new Date();
console.log("date is ->",d," and day of the week is->", d.getDay());
console.log("Now changing date");
d.setDate(4);
console.log("date is ->",d," and day of the week is->", d.getDay());
```

**Output**

```
date is -> Wed Jan 01 2014 19:46:07 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)  and day of the week is-> 3 VM331:3
Now changing date VM331:4
date is -> Sat Jan 04 2014 19:46:07 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)  and day of the week is-> 6
```

So it will be a better to have an integer, for lowering the network traffic too.

Comment: ok nice to see the snippets because I really thought that Javascripts sunday is not index 0 like in c#.

Answer (score 1):

"Best" is subjective, but I will give you my opinion.

From a raw JavaScript perspective, the day of the week is 0 (Sunday) through 6 (Saturday). You can see that [in the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay).  It aligns exactly with C#'s `DayOfWeek` enumeration, so you certainly can pass that, but I wouldn't recommend it, for a few reasons.

- What are you going to do with it in JavaScript once you have it?  The `Date` object has a `getDay()`, but it doesn't have `setDay()`, so you can't adjust an existing date to a particular day of the week unless you're going to do your own computation or use a library like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com).
- Moment.js has [a `day` function for that](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/day/), so you could pass it like this:

  ```
  moment().day(0);
  ```

  But you could just as easily pass the full day name:

  ```
  moment().day("Sunday");
  ```

  Or you could use [another function](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/iso-weekday/) if you needed Sunday to be represented by a 7

  ```
  moment().isoWeekday(7);
  ```
- That brings up an interesting point, which is that the *standard* for dates and times is ISO-8601, and that standard uses [weekdays numbered 1 through 7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date).  If you're going to send data out of your application in numeric form, shouldn't it conform to a standard? I think so, but then again - who's to say that the consumer of this data will understand that that standard is in use?  With just a simple integer, it can be really hard to tell.
- Then think for a second about JSON serialization.  The JSON format was designed to be more compact than XML, but still be human readable.  Which of these looks more readable to you?

  ```
  { days: [0,1,2] }
  ```

  or

  ```
  { days: ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday"] }
  ```

  Not convinced?  How about when passing a full date and time?

  ```
  { date: 1388453025678 }
  ```

  or

  ```
  { date: "2013-12-31T01:23:45.678Z" }
  ```

  Clearly, the second choice is more human readable in both scenarios.
- In general, it's an accepted practice to serialize C# enums as strings rather than as integers, because otherwise they can lose their original meaning.  In the above example, what if I had called the variable `foo` instead of `days`.  With the numeric form, you'd have no idea what the data was representing.

Therefore, my recommendation would be to **pass the string version**.  There are lots of advantages, and there are only two disadvantages I can think of, which are:

- The numeric form is more compact - but that's not what JSON aims for anyway.  If smaller data is what you're after then you'd probably be better off with a binary serialization format like Google's Protocol Buffers.  But that's usually overkill - I wouldn't go down that road unless other parts of your application demanded it.
- The weekday names are in English.  Personally, I don't think that's so bad in the JSON itself, but some might prefer that be localized.  You can always do it later though:

  ```
  moment().day("Sunday").lang('fr').format("dddd");  // "dimanche"
  ```

You also mentioned Angular.js, which does have a [date filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3adate), but you're not going to be able to bind just a day of week to it either way.  So that doesn't really factor into the decision.